# Problem backing up certain files with rsync

Tags: backup, rsync, truecrypt

I am trying to backup several files with rsync, most of them work, except the files which are actually truecrypt encrypted containers. I have a hidden volume within the files, and I wonder if this is the problem.

I understand the point of a truecrypt hidden volume is that it should not be able to be detected, but I took this to mean it is indistinguishable from garbage/random data.

However, when I make changes by placing new files in the hidden volume in the file container, rsync does not detect that the file has changed.

Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TrueCrypt not change file timestamps and size.

- touch -m container
- rsync -c ....

man rsync:

```
-c, --checksum              skip based on checksum, not mod-time & size
```

Comment: I really would prefer the `touch` method as otherwise rsync has to read every file for checksumming just to catch the one TC container.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that TC makes sure that changes to the file doesn't modify the file times, so you must either touch the file or tell rsync to use checksums to determine what to back up.